# Shell Script to Connect to Ignite

Tags: shell, ignite

I want to connect to `Ignite` DB via the `Shell` script and query the database.

tried using the `sqlline.sh` and not able to query it.

```
/opt/ignite/bin/sqlline.sh --verbose=true -u jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/ -e "select * from user"
```

Comment: How did you create the table(s)? What configuration parameters? How many nodes? Did you get any error messages? If so, what? Look on both the client and server sides.

Answer (score 1):

`sqlline` has `--run` parameter which can run scripts from file.

Consider:

```
% echo "select * from user" > script.sql
% bin/sqlline.sh -u 'jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/' --outputformat=vertical --run=./script.sql 2>/dev/null
ID    1
NAME  John

ID    10
NAME  Doe
```

I'm not sure, maybe you can also use standard input, pipe commands in.